# How to alphabetize list using getchar

Tags: c, getchar

I'm currently trying to attempt to alphabetize a list. I'm trying to have the user input a line containing the number of words to sort. Each following line will be entering a new word. The words will not contain spaces and will end with a line return. I know the easy way would be to read everything in using `scanf` or `fgets`, however my microprocessor cannot handle those functions forcing me to use `getchar()`. As of now, when it prints out the sorted list, it just prints garbage. I feel like something is wrong with my code, but I am very new to programming and cannot figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

     int main()
    {
        int i, j;
        char  string[10][20], temp[20];
        int num;

        while(1)
        {
            char ch = getchar();
            if(ch == 0)
                continue;
            if(ch <= 0x39 && ch >= 0x30)
            {
                putchar(ch);
                num = ch - 0x30;
            }
            if(ch == 0x0D)
                printf("\n\r");
            if (ch <= 0x7A && ch >= 0x61)
            {
                putchar(ch);
                for(i=0; i<=num; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<=20; j++)
                        string[i][j] = ch;
                }
            }
            if(ch== 0x20)
                break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < num - 1 ; i++)
           {
               for (j = i + 1; j < num; j++)
               {
                   if (strcmp(string[i], string[j]) > 0)
                   {
                       strcpy(temp, string[i]);
                       strcpy(string[i], string[j]);
                       strcpy(string[j], temp);
                   }
               }
           }
           printf("\nSorted Names\n");
           for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
           {
               printf("%s\n", string[i]);
           }
           return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `j<=20` and friends should be `j < 20` to avoid going off the end by 1, and you're not null-terminating any of your strings. Your first `for` loop just fills all your `char` arrays with the same character. What kind of microprocessor "can't handle" `scanf()` and `fgets()`?

Comment: Not small enough that it doesn't have a C runtime, just small-enough that they didn't put anything *in it* ? How odd. What microprocessor is this anyway?

Comment: How would I null-terminate my strings? also how would I fix that first 'for' loop to have it be the number of words to sort? And I'm using microblaze.

Comment: I am using microblaze for the nexys 3

Comment: Genuinely without trying to be funny, you'd null-terminate your strings and fix your `for` loop by working on easier problems until you're familiar with the basics of C. If you're "very new to programming", there's really no substitute for starting at the beginning and trying to get the hang of it. Some kind of decent tutorial will prove invaluable.

Comment: No, I've tried both of those and nothing happens. And it was not my code as I ran it through a normal gcc compiler and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths C is very popular in embedded processors, (billions made each year) many of which find functions like `scanf()` to be _very_ expensive in code space, easily taking up 10% of program space.

Comment: Curious, why code with `if(ch <= 0x39 && ch >= 0x30)` when `if(ch <= '9' && ch >= '0')` appears, IMO, to be some much easier to understand?

Comment: @chux just practicing using hex and the ascii table

Comment: @chux: I've always been under the impression that code was stored in some kind of memory, rather than in microprocessors (registers and cache memory obviously aside).

Comment: @Paul Griffiths Check the micro controllers at [Micro Chip](http://www.microchip.com/).  Microprocessor, memory, non-volatile memory, IO, sensors, etc. all in one chip.  Lots of money to be made in this industry segment.

Comment: @chux: Semantics to my mind (i.e. 'microprocessor' vs 'microprocessor plus a bunch of other stuff on one chip') but fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to NULL-terminate the strings you read in.  So you should change your check for a return to:

```
if ( ch == 0x0D )
{
    string[i][j] = '\0';
    printf( "\n\r" );
}
```

Second, you are reading a character at a time, but then you do a for loop for each character.  This is completely wrong.  You need to track i and j within the while loop and put each character into the correct spot as you go.  I'm not going to write this out for you as it's pretty simple:  Get rid of the double for loops when a character between 'a' and 'z' is received and just set string[i][j] = ch and then increment j.  Just check to make sure j is less than 20 first.

Then, you just increment i every time you see a 0x0D character, and change your while loop to exit when i >= num.

Also, I would put your read of num in a separate loop before the one reading the words so that you can check for the user entering data in the proper order.  You don't want to start reading words until the user has entered a number so you know how many to read.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful and makes it very clear to understand. I appreciate this very much.

Comment: You don't terminate strings with a `NULL`, but with a `0`, or a `'\0`. `NULL` is for pointers.

Comment: I was thinking of the previous answer I was just looking at where I was talking about pointers to strings, and I just mistyped.

Comment: Paul Griffiths: `NULL`, `0`, and `'\0'` are all equal (though of different type).

Comment: @rampion only when you're talking about pointers.  NULL can be defined as ((void*)0) which isn't valid when used with non-pointers.  See also http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html

Comment: @rampion: Both `0` and `(void *) 0` can serve as a null pointer constant, but if `NULL` is defined as `(void *) 0`, then `string[i][j] = NULL` isn't going to lead to happiness.